# What does error bars/.cd do?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfkeys

In `pgfplots`, if you want error bars, you have to write `error bars/.cd` into each `addplot` that should have error bars. What does it mean and what does it do and why do I need it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cd means change directory.

This command will prefix all successive keys by the key "error bars/" automatically

**Edit:** Why do you need it? I do not have the time to check the code, but I suppose that drawing an error bar needs to do something a little different than drawing a normal plot. So it probably needs to redefine some keys or functions.

For example:

```
\addplot[mark=o]
```

will use the key `mark` (probably `/pgfplots/mark`)

But

```
\addplot[error bars/.cd,mark=o]
```

will use the key `error bars/mark` (probably `/pgfplots/error bars/mark`), that may have a totally different meaning, adapted to plot a graph with error bars...